# Assigning a general result from Solve to a variable

Tags: equation-solving

Thank you Michel, for the help. 
Now, I want to get the result and assign it to a variable and then make a new function. How can I do that? I was tryng this way with "First", as follow the picture, but...didn't work... Thanks in advance!!! :)

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, the issues it raises are too restricted to the situation and needs of its poster. Answers will not benefit others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `post` as

```
ClearAll[post]; 
post[t_]: = First[p /. Solve[tpos[p] == t, p]]
```

before using `post[t]`.